# How to find max occurring label for each GROUP and replace rest label by the new label (max occurrence)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dummy dataset.

```
sr <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
w_type <- c("a","b","a","c","c","c","d")
segment <- c("high","Low","high","high","low","high","low")
df <- data.frame(sr,w_type,segment)
```

For each sr number, we need to have unique w_type and segment. The w_type and segment must be the most occurring w_type or segment for each sr number.

I could find most occurring w_type yet not sure how to combine with original dataframe. 
`df %>% group_by(sr) %>% count(w_type) %>% top_n(1)` .Also as in case of "Segment" here. When frequency are equal, say for sr # 2 we have equal number of "high" and "low" count, in this case I want to take the any of the two segment "high" or "low".

[original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK2A5.png)
[New/output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsdtJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we can find the frequency count with `Mode` function after grouping by 'sr'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(sr) %>%
   mutate(new_segment = Mode(segment))
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   sr [2]
#     sr w_type segment new_segment
#  <dbl> <fct>  <fct>   <fct>      
#1     1 a      high    high       
#2     1 b      Low     high       
#3     1 a      high    high       
#4     2 c      high    high       
#5     2 c      low     high       
#6     2 c      high    high       
#7     2 d      low     high
```

where

```
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks indeed Arun, works like a charm .I did find a link exactly using mode function and was customizing with my dataframe.